# Profile Error deploying via Ant - Manage Customer Users requires Edit Contact

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile, ant

I have the below setting in one of the profile:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>ManageCssUsers</name>
</userPermissions>


<objectPermissions>
    <allowCreate>false</allowCreate>
    <allowDelete>false</allowDelete>
    <allowEdit>false</allowEdit>
    <allowRead>true</allowRead>
    <modifyAllRecords>false</modifyAllRecords>
    <object>Contact</object>
    <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
</objectPermissions>
```

But when I try to deploy this profile through ant migration I get an error saying - `Manage Customer Users requires Edit Contact`. I see it is because in target org `'Manage Customer Users'` app permission is checked.

When deploying , should'nt the profile metadata change override the one in target env

Comment: permissions are additive in salesforce.

Comment: It under profile->app permission->Manage Customer user? Do you mean it cannot be changed using metadata?

Comment: Yes, permission will be deployed in an additive manner. We can only grant permissions through metadata deploy.

Comment: Thanks!So to remove the permission, we have to do it manually? Is there any official document which describes this?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140988/migration-of-standard-object-permissions-using-meta-data-deploy

Comment: To "turn off" permissions at the org, you have to edit the XML manually and then migrate.

Answer (score 1):

So, According to Salesforce (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) if you want to disable the permission on profile then you have to add code that explicitly indicates disabled permissions.For example, add the following code to the Profile metadata .xml file before deploying into a target org: `<value>false</value>`.

Comment: This permission (`ManageCssUsers`) corresponds to the "Edit Self-Service Users" checkbox on the profile.

Comment: Gotach , I see needs to be added to .xml of profile.

Comment: One more thing https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_customer_users.htm. So `Edit Self-Service Users` is now renamed as `Manage Customer Users`. Glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like in my code base I don't store profile xml file. I only have xyzprofile.profile and not xyzprofile.xml

Comment: It should be `xyzprofile.profile` not `xyzprofile.xml`

Comment: What place do I add in .profile file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84353/discussion-between-pragati-jain-and-sfdcbat).